# Is there a coalesce-like function in Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, xls, coalesce

I need to fill a cell with the first non-empty entry in a set of columns (from left to right) in the same row - similar to coalesce() in SQL.

In the following example sheet

```
---------------------------------------
|     |  A   |   B   |   C   |    D   |
---------------------------------------
|  1  |      |   x   |   y   |    z   |
---------------------------------------
|  2  |      |       |   y   |        |
---------------------------------------
|  3  |      |       |       |    z   |
---------------------------------------
```

I want to put a cell function in each cell of row A such that I will get:

```
---------------------------------------
|     |  A   |   B   |   C   |    D   |
---------------------------------------
|  1  |  x   |   x   |   y   |    z   |
---------------------------------------
|  2  |  y   |       |   y   |        |
---------------------------------------
|  3  |  z   |       |       |    z   |
---------------------------------------
```

I know I could do this with a cascade of IF functions, but in my real sheet, I have 30 columns to select from, so I would be happy if there were a simpler way.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
=INDEX(B2:D2,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(B2:D2),FALSE))
```

This is an Array Formula.  After entering the formula, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to have Excel evaluate it as an Array Formula.  This returns the first nonblank value of the given range of cells.  For your example, the formula is entered in the column with the header "a"

```
    A   B   C   D
1   x   x   y   z
2   y       y   
3   z           z
```

Comment: Very helpful.  If you're using this to coalesce the results of a series of vlookups, replace the `isblank` with `isna`

Comment: Is there a way of reversing this -- favouring the rightmost column first?

Comment: @TimBarrass you probably don't need this anymore, but try this for right to left: =INDEX(B2:D2,1+SUM(IF(B2:D2=B2:D2,1,0))-MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(B2:D2,1,N(IF({1},SUM(IF(B2:D2=B2:D2,1,0))+COLUMN(B2)-COLUMN(B2:D2))))&""="",FALSE))

Comment: Worked well for me thanks. I just had to use =INDEX(B2:D2,MATCH(FALSE,B2:D2="",FALSE)) because my blanks were blanks from a preceding function / formula.

Answer (score 39):

I used:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),B1,A1)
```

This tests the if the first field you want to use is blank then use the other.  You can use a "nested if" when you have multiple fields.

Comment: it shouldn't - it only tests for two fields, imagine you search for first non-empty in a lot more, eg. whole row

Answer (score 17):

Or if you want to compare individual cells, you can create a Coalesce function in VBA:

```
Public Function Coalesce(ParamArray Fields() As Variant) As Variant

    Dim v As Variant

    For Each v In Fields
        If "" & v <> "" Then
            Coalesce = v
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Coalesce = ""

End Function
```

And then call it in Excel. In your example the formula in A1 would be:

```
=Coalesce(B1, C1, D1)
```

Comment: I prefer this solution, this is a more standard formula usage then using an array formula. Thanks.

Comment: @MattRoy not so _standard_ since it forces you to save your workbook as XLSB or XLSA

Comment: I am a complete noob for VBA, but how do I run the function once I have it entered? When I try using it, it gives me a #NAME error in the cell formula.

Comment: Same here, #NAME error. I saved the file as `.xlsm` which did not help. Where do I have to place the code?

Answer (score 7):

Taking the VBA approach a step further, I've re-written it to allow a combination of both (or either) individual cells and cell ranges:

```
Public Function Coalesce(ParamArray Cells() As Variant) As Variant

    Dim Cell As Variant
    Dim SubCell As Variant

    For Each Cell In Cells
        If VarType(Cell) > vbArray Then
            For Each SubCell In Cell
                If VarType(SubCell) <> vbEmpty Then
                    Coalesce = SubCell
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next
        Else
            If VarType(Cell) <> vbEmpty Then
                Coalesce = Cell
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Coalesce = ""

End Function
```

So now in Excel you could use any of the following formulas in A1:

```
=Coalesce(B1, C1, D1)
=Coalesce(B1, C1:D1)
=Coalesce(B1:C1, D1)
=Coalesce(B1:D1)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you know there will not be any overlap across columns, or want the overlap, then this is a pretty fast way to solve for a coalesce.  The below formula does not apply to your values and columns, but rather to my mock-up so you will need to adjust to make it relevant.

```
=LEFT(TRIM(CONCATENATE(Q38,R38,S38,T38,U38,V38,W38,X38,Y38)),1)
```

Answer (score 4):

With the updated IFS function in excel you don't need to nest.  You can try something like

1. Create a blank cell to the right
   Then enter.

```
=IFS(ISBLANK(A1),B1,ISBLANK(A1),C1,ISBLANK(A1),D1)
```

Highlight column and paste as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to coalesce to 0, which is a very common use case, you can simply use the `SUM()` function around a single value. As a convenience that one treats all blanks as zero, and it's extra convenient since it's so short.

Not a generic solution like the other answers, but a helpful shortcut in many cases where that's exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

With the new Excel Array functions available in MS365. You can do the following:

```
=LET(
RangeForCoalesce, #YourRangeGoesHere,
CHOOSECOLS(TOROW(RangeForCoalesce, 1), 1)
)
```

Excel is getting extremely efficient in handling dynamic ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the array enter the variables that are not allowed.

```
Function Coalesce(ParamArray Fields() As Variant) As Variant

    Dim v As Variant

    For Each v In Fields
        If IsError(Application.Match(v, Array("", " ", 0), False)) Then
            Coalesce = v
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Coalesce = ""

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many cells you want to check, you can chain together multiple ISBLANK checks.

For instance, when checking columns A, B, then C:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),IF(ISBLANK(B1),C1,B1),A1)
```

For columns A, B, C, and D:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),IF(ISBLANK(B1),IF(ISBLANK(C1),D1,C1),B1),A1)
```

... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party and leveraging @AndyMC's answer you can use the following to evaluate vlookups, index(match()) etc. to coalesce your formula statements.

```
Public Function Coalesce(ParamArray Fields() As Variant) As Variant

    Dim v As Variant

    For Each v In Fields
        
        If Not IsError(v) Then
            
            Coalesce = v
            
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Coalesce = CVErr(xlErrNA)

End Function
```

and use it in your Worksheet as followed: `=Coalesce(INDEX(SHEET1!$A:$AF,MATCH(Main!$Q36,SHEET1!$I:$I,0),MATCH(Main!D$34,SHEET1!$1:$1,0)),INDEX(SHEET2!A:CR,MATCH(Main!$Q36,SHEET2!$M:$M,0),MATCH("SOMETHING",SHEET2!$1:$1,0)))`

For the first statement that does not return `#N/A` it will return the actual matched value.

Answer (score 0):

`IF` macro would require evaluating things twice, but nowadays there's a family of `IF` macros, e.g., `IFNA` coalesces `#N/A` into 0:

[image: IF macro family]