# In excel I want to use data from multiple worksheets in one cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, lookup, vlookup

all

Im trying to find a way to pull data from multiple worksheets based on wheter the cell is blank or not.

For example

if **"worksheet A has a number in cell a23"** then I want that number to be entered into the a23 cell on worksheet d, but if a23 is blank then I want to use the number in cell a23 of worksheet b to be entered into worksheet d, and so on ...

Please let me know if this is clear enough. So far I have came up with this nested if function

`=IF('worksheetB'!E9,'worksheetB'!E9,IF('worksheetB="",'worksheetc'!E23,IF('worksheetc'!E23="",'worksheetde21)))`

which , which will not work past 2 workbooks.

Thank you

Comment: How many work sheets might there be?

Comment: Something like this but handling sheets dynamically may get tricky. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103881/is-there-a-coalesce-like-function-in-excel

Comment: Have you tried to stagger and your data to multiple cells, and then combine the resultant data?

Comment: Thank you all I do not know how to stagger data in excel @AlanWaage do you have any examples?

Comment: Perform parts of your logic in more than one cell, then have another cell reference them.  Like in A1 have '=IF('somewhereelse1', 'somewhereelse1',if(somewhereelse2,somwhereelse2,"")  then in B1, do 3 and 4.  Then in C1 do '=IF(A1, A1, IF(B1, B1, (IF .....))'  etc.