# Excel - Filling a blank value in one column with a value from another

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a way to fill in the blank in come column with the value from another. I have one column, Mode of Communication, and then there are columns for "Email", "Phone", and "Chat". I want to fill in the blanks from Mode of Communication with the value, if present, from the three other columns. Is there a way to do this?

Example:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this question it's very similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103881/is-there-a-coalesce-like-function-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear if there will only be content in one of the columns, or multiple columns, and if you want only one value returned, or all of them.

An easy way to get all of them is to concatenate the strings

```
=J23&" "&K23&" "&L23
```

If there will only be an entry in one of the three columns, you can leave out the &" " parts (which just insert a space between each entry) and you will get the single value. 
If you have a preferred order, then using IF will allow you to check first for Phone, then email etc.