# Excel-text result of 2 text columns

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 columns (A & B) with text. Column A has a variety of text values and blanks. Column B always has matching text values to those values in column A, except for some blank values in column A will have a new value in column B. Ex:

Column A

```
blue
blank
red
blank
```

column B

```
blue
blank
red
yellow
```

I would want column C to display (in order)

```
blue
blank
red
yellow
```

Can a formula be created for this?

Comment: So since they match just return column B? there is no difference between C and B.

Comment: Oops sorry, sometimes there are blanks in column B, so I would need to take the values for those rows from column A

Comment: ah so if both blank then blank otherwise which ever is not blank?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103881/is-there-a-coalesce-like-function-in-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple IF with AND:

```
=IF(AND(A1<>"",B1<>""),A1,A1&B1)
```

[image]