# Nested if else and is blank in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

Column A,B and C are dates
Condition:

If column A date is present use the same date.
If date in A column is blank then use date from column B.
If column B is blank then use date from column C.

C has the final date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a coalesce-like function in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103881/is-there-a-coalesce-like-function-in-excel)

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK(A1),B1,A1) something like this, but nested more conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(A1=TODAY(),A1,IF(A1="",B1,IF(B1="",C1)))
```

Comment: I wanna compare dates from previous month so what function other than today can I use?

Comment: @Vaish please edit your question to describe the new/alternate specifications, or open a new question for the new issue.

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK(A1),IF(ISBLANK(B1),C1,B1),A1)